# Sending shell script command keystrokes to a remote shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

Is it possible to make the script run when it shifts from normal mode to the interactive mode.

```
#/bash/bin  
sudo gatttool -b 80:EA:CA:00:00:03 -I  
# All these commands are typed in interactive mode  
connect  
while [ 1 ]; do  
char_read_hnd 0x0030 > a.txt  
done  
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for

```
 sudo gatttool -b 80:EA:CA:00:00:03 -I  <<EOF
 # All these commands are entered in interactive mode  
connect  
while [ 1 ]; do  
char_read_hnd 0x0030 > a.txt  
done  
exit 1
EOF
```

the syntax `cmd <<EOF` (lines ) `EOF` (on a line of its onw) is called a here doc.

Comment: more complicated tasks involving e.g. waiting for a prompt or a particular response from the remote host should be done with the `expect` scripting language, or perl's `Expect.pm` module or python's `pexpect`.  Other languages also have similar expect-like libraries.

Comment: @cas Yes  _<<EOF_ does the trick, but I have to wait for a particular message from remote host to execute the other commands. As I am new to scripting language, I will have to look into other scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just write or read you can use one string command like this:

```
gatttool -i hci0 -b device=MAC --char-write-req -a handle=0x0001 -n value=0x0001

gatttool -i hci0 -b device=MAC --char-read -a handle=0x0001
```

I found it here: http://www.mathieupassenaud.fr/control-your-plugs-with-bluetooth-and-bash-scripts/.

To find more options see `gatttool --help-all`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect for shell or pexpect for python.

I think you're searching for something like this:
https://www.torsten-traenkner.de/wissen/smarthome/heizung.php